# Does css will block the document ready function

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I have large a css file in a page, then my document.ready execution will wait until the loading of the css file or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="large-amount-file.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
        <p>Click me away!</p>
        <p>Click me too!</p>
        <p>fsdfsd</p>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert("hi");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope!! `$(window).load` will wait for that.

Comment: can you explain clearly why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready` executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready while 
`$(window).load` executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.

So large CSS files do not block the `$(document).ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

> Does css will block the document ready function

Answer is **No**

`$(document).ready` means when the Document is ready. And here the Document is referred to the HTML part. So When the HTML is completely loaded the script inside the `$(document).ready` will execute. It will not wait for other script's or CSS files to load as it is not considered as document.

From the **[Jquery Document](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.